# Strange distortion of the image after rendering

Tags: rendering

When I look at the scene in the "rendered" mode everything is OK, 
[image]
but when I render image to png file, I get this strange distortion. 
[image]
Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: what modifiers do you have on the model?

Comment: @Denis Good question :) I forgot that I was experimenting with Simple deform modifier on the ocean, and forgot to remove it. Thank you! If you add it as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason for difference between the render and 3D View is modifiers that are disabled in view or have different setting for view and render.

[image]